# Override appsettings.json Array With Env Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, docker-compose, appsettings

I have this array in my `appsettings.json`:

```json
  "ServiceDefinitions": [
    {
      "Name": "encryption-api",
      "Url": "http://localhost:5032",
      "ApiKey": "",
      "ExposedEndpoints": [
        "encrypt",
        "decrypt"
      ]
    }
  ],
```

I want to be able to override this with an environment variable. I've added the env vars to the configuration builder like this, which seems to work for other values:

```cs
builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

And then I've attempted to set this in my Docker Compose file with:

```
environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://gateway:8080/
      - ServiceDefinitions="{\"Name\":\"encryption-api\",\"Url\":\"http://encryption-api:80\",\"ApiKey\":\"\",\"ExposedEndpoints\":[\"encrypt\",\"decrypt\"]}"
```

However, it's still picking up the value from the json file rather than the env var. I've also tried setting it inside `[]` but that makes no difference.

How can I do this?

Comment: I believe you would need to break apart the object and do something like: `- ServiceDefinitions__Name="encryption-api"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#environment-variables) regarding app configuration.

You are going to want to make sure that your Json provider is registered before your environment variables provider. Then you'll want to setup your environment variables in your Docker file as follows:

```
environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://gateway:8080/
      - ServiceDefinitions__0__Name="encryption-api"
      - ServiceDefinitions__0__Url="http://encryption-api:80"
      - ServiceDefinitions__0__ApiKey=""
      - ServiceDefinitions__0__ExposedEndpoints__0="encrypt"
      - ServiceDefinitions__0__ExposedEndpoints__1="decrypt"
```

Comment: Would it need to be `ServiceDefinitions__0__XXX` since `ServiceDefinitions` is an array in itself?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I missed that. I updated my answer

Comment: Will try when I get home and mark as accepted if this works. Thanks!